# Get 2 Parent level Joomla Title PHP

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I know how to get the *Current Page Title*, also I know how to get the *Menu Active Page Title* but I need to actually get the 2 parent Active Menu via PHP.

### Active Menu Title

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$title = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

### Menu Example

- 1st Level - **CARS**
- - 2nd Level - **FERRARI**
- - - 3rd Level - **F50**

If I am at the 3 level menu **F50** how can I get the CARS active menu title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method, i used this:

```
//import to faster development
jimport( 'joomla.application.categories' );

$options    = array();
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);
$category   = $categories->get($this->category->id);

$parent     = $category->getParent();
```

And here is the magic

```
//here you get the grandparent category
$grandtemp = $categories->get($parent->id);
$grandparent = $grandtemp->getParent();

//print the values of parent of parent (1st level)
print_r($grandparent)
```

if you have any question you can comment

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$baseId = $menu->getActive($params)->tree[0]; //tree[1] for the second parent etc 

//query the database to find the title
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT title FROM #__menu WHERE id=".$baseId;
$db->setQuery( $query );
$topParentTitle = $db->loadResult();
```